# Simple method of detecting and reporting server outage?

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring

I'm looking for a super simple way to monitor one server from another, in case the other goes down (e.g. based on ping), and then send an email if it does.  Is there anything out there like this installable via the standard package manager (debian)?  I'm aware of things like nagios and monit, but these are much more complex than I need.

(The servers are on a private network, so I can't use third party web services)

Thanks

Comment: ICMP echo requests are by no means sufficient to monitor a server. You need to monitor the actual services running on the server. After all, it is those services, which are important to the users. There are plenty of ways a system can crash that will leave it capable of responding to ICMP echo requests and nothing else.

Comment: @kasperd - In this case I'm monitoring for a very specific failure scenario, and ping will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looing for something installable via package manager but if you are looking for some simple script the below one do a trick for you

```
        SERVERIP=192.168.0.1
        NOTIFYEMAIL=testing@example.com

        ping -c 3 $SERVERIP > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
        mail -s "Server $SERVERIP is down" -t "$NOTIFYEMAIL" < /dev/null 
        fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to send email when you don't receive a ping response, something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/sh
while oping -c 20 -i 1 -Z 15 otherhost; do
    :
done
echo "otherhost is down" | mail -s "otherhost is down" recipient@domain
```

This needs oping from the eponymous package. The switches above cause it to send 20 pings at 1 second intervals; if more than 15% of the pings go unreplied (that's 3 packets), oping will exit unsuccessfully, causing the while loop to exit and the mail command to be run. If you also install the moreutils package, you can even easily cause the last (unsuccessful) oping output to be included in the mail like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while chronic oping -c 20 -i 1 -Z 15 otherhost; do
    :
done | mail -E -s "otherhost is down" recipient@domain
```